# How to declare a structure in C at root level?

Tags: c, structure

I have the following code, I declare the `mainObj` structure (user defined type `obj`) before calling it in the `mainObj_init` function. Do you know why Visual Studio underlines `mainObj` like it's not declared already?

```
#include <SDL.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct obj
{
    SDL_Surface *pSprite;
    SDL_Texture *pTexture;
    SDL_Rect pos;
} obj;

obj mainObj;

void mainObj_init(unsigned char * filename)
{
    mainObj->pSprite = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
}
```

Comment: from your example it looks like you should have an obj named mainObj at global scope... maybe the underline doesn't mean what you thing it should... what does the error say?

Comment: Which occurrence of `mainObj` does it underline? `mainObj` is an object of struct type, not a pointer, so you need to refer to `mainObj.pSprite`, not `mainObj->pSprite`.

Comment: Listen to your compiler. It probably told you, that `mainObj` isn't a pointer. It's a structure, you must use `.` to access its elements, not `->`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that this statement is wrong

```
mainObj->pSprite = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
```

There shall be

```
mainObj.pSprite = SDL_LoadBMP(filename);
```

`mainObj` is not declared as a pointer.